# Efeito com jQuery travando sem motivos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou usando o seguinte comando jQuery:

```
   var timer1;
        SemConflito("#lp-1").on('mouseover', function(){
            clearTimeout(timer1);
            timer1 = setTimeout(function(){
                SemConflito("#lp-1-hover").stop().slideDown({duration: 400, easing: 'easeInCubic'}); }, 300);
    });
```

O efeito é simples, quando o usuário colocar o mouse sobre a div id "lp-1", uma outra div irá surgir com o efeito "slidedown". O problema é que está travando o efeito. A div vai surgindo e trava no meio, não chega a aparecer completamente. Tem casos (como no Mozilla) que dificilmente a div aparece.

Não sei o que é.. Preciso muito de ajuda.

Observação: Aquele "SemConflito" é uma variável que fiz:

```
var SemConflito = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Exemplo funcional: http://jsfiddle.net/vn1b4sck/

Explicando melhor como funciona esse efeito: no site há uma parte onde aparecem 4 divs, lado a lado. Cada div com seu conteúdo próprio. Quando o usuário passar o mouse sobre uma delas, desce uma nova div em cima da atual, com novas informações. Quando o mouse sair, a div desaparece. O problema está quando o usuário passa o mouse na div e vai para a outra, e me parece que nessa transição de movimento, a altura do efeito buga, fazendo com que a div apenas "desça" até a altura que ficou da última vez.

Talvez exista algum jeito mais prático ou até um plugin simples pra isso.

Comment: verifique no firebug se há algum erro no javascript ou no chrome, na consola do javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrumei!!

Foi bobagem, mas decidi setar a altura da div pelo próprio jQuery e tirar o do css.
Funcionou!! Não está dando conflito de altura.. :D

```
SemConflito('#lp-1-hover').css('height', '292');
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi você quer dar um atraso na abertura do `.slideDown`, você pode conseguir esse efeito usando o `.delay` como no exemplo abaixo:

jquery:

```
var SemConflito = jQuery.noConflict();
SemConflito("#lp-1").on('mouseover', function () {
    SemConflito("#lp-1-hover").delay(500).slideDown({
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'easeInCubic',
    });
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/1hxrx3z6/).

Comment: Não seria exatamente isso. Usei um timer no meu para o efeito não aparecer de cara. E funciona como eu quero. A não ser que esteja sendo ele o causador do meu problema, que é o efeito slidedown bugar e a altura travar num valor "x".

Comment: @Ricardo O .delay serve justamente pra isso, se não precisa fechar depois que sai com o mouse, é mais fácil ainda, editei a resposta...

Comment: De fato, e até deixa o script mais limpo. Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Testei o seu código aqui e funcionou, fiz apenas uma modificação:

```
SemConflito("#lp-1-hover").stop().slideDown(400,'easeInCubic');
```

Fiz o include do Jquery UI, também é necessário por causa do easing.
http://jqueryui.com/

Veja o teste que fiz: http://jsfiddle.net/21045e0y/2/

Comment: Um exemplo do meu código: http://jsfiddle.net/vn1b4sck/

Comment: @Ricardo fiz novas alterações: http://jsfiddle.net/vn1b4sck/3/ o problema está ao setar a altura da div, o script slideDown também faz isso e entra em conflito com o seu código.

Comment: Valeu Felipe. Já consegui resolver meu problema, apenas ajustei a hight da div somente pelo jQuery e não pelo css.

Answer (score 1):

Considere resolver só com css `transition`. Um exemplo no fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/zeqeyo/1/edit

Comment: Se eu pudesse fazer o site com css puro, ficaria bem melhor mesmo!! Problema é que eu preciso fazer com que ele rode em navegadores mais antigos, infelizmente.